# OR statement doesnt seem to working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Have I used the OR syntax correctly here, it doesnt seem to be bringing any data back when it should?

```
WHERE 
        ph.SALES_DOCUMENT_NUM IN (SELECT ph.Sales_document_num FROM package_header ph WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) = ''23-DEC-2020''
    or
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) = ''29-DEC-2020'')
        and 
        ph.Package_Num <> 0
```

Comment: off topic but the date formatting - you don't need to convert to/from date/char 3x.  Just  TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd')

Comment: [Date literals in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1) are written like `date '1970-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify it to just the subquery. When that works, the outer query will, too:

```
SELECT ph.Sales_document_num 
FROM package_header ph 
WHERE 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) = ''23-DEC-2020''
    or
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) = ''29-DEC-2020''
```

Right now, we can see the subquery closes **before** the final `and` condition. However, this last condition references the table alias from the subquery; this is probably a mistake. The final `and ph.Package_Num <> 0` expression should be moved inside the early parentheses.

Rule of thumb: When `OR` conditions are involved, the first thing to check is the parentheses. Once you address that, the second thing to check... is also the parentheses. Even then, the third thing to check is **still** the parentheses.

While I'm here, you can simplify this to avoid repeating the same complicated expression and remove the `OR` completely:

```
WHERE 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(''19700101'',''yyyymmdd'') + + (FLOOR(ph.change_date/24/60/60)))) IN (''23-DEC-2020'', ''29-DEC-2020'')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parenthesis as follows:

```
WHERE ph.SALES_DOCUMENT_NUM IN 
      (SELECT ph.Sales_document_num 
         FROM package_header ph 
        WHERE (
              condition1 
               or
              condition2
              )
        and ph.Package_Num <> 0
```